# Bug in timing of chat room

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

There are different time showing in [all chat rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) and in [Posse Commitatus chat-room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus). For more information check below images: (click to enlarge)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for editing @Sha Wiz Dow Ard as I don't have enough reputation to upload images.

Comment: Is this same use case happening at your place also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last message is a *(removed)* stub. That doesn't count as a message in the roomlist (because it really isn't one anymore), but since it is displayed inside the room, the "time elapsed" indicators obviously have to take it into account.

The 14 days you see on the outside is the 5 days plus nine days you see on the inside. In particular, note that it says "14d ago – jadarnel27", not "14d ago – Jeremy Banks".

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now I understood. Actually, there was same issue with [Data Explorer Discussions room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/495/data-explorer-discussions) also.